# Modify o/p date in email messaging

Tags: apex, trigger

I have trigger where it sends email when record is deleted. It works fine but date format isn't getting right in email. It's showing yr-mm-dd 00:00:00 whereas i just need only date in mm-dd-yr format, any idea how to change it?

```
trigger DeleteEmail on Contract__c (after delete) {
    Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(trigger.size);
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new 
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

    for (Contract__c cc : Trigger.old) {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        email.setToAddresses(new String[] {'abc@abc.com'});
        email.setSubject('Contract '+cc.Name+ ' has been Deleted');
        email.setHtmlBody('This message is to alert you that ' + cc.Name + ' has been Deleted <br/><br/>'+'Contract Name: '+cc.Name+ ' <br></br> Contract ID: '+cc.Contract_ID__c+ ' <br></br> Contract Start Date: '+cc.Contract_Start_Date__c+ ' <br></br> Contract End Date : '+cc.Contract_End_Date__c );
        emails.add(email);
    }
    Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to use: `cc.Contract_Start_Date__c.Date().format()`. It sounds like the fields were configured as Date/Time values instead of Date values, which is why they include the time component by default. Using date() returns just the date portion.

Comment: Awesome it worked

Comment: My test class isn't giving me coverage, what should i modify it to give me enough coverage to push it to prod?                                                                          @isTest
private class ContractDeleteEmailTest {

    static testMethod void myUnitTest() {
    
    Corporate_Contract__c cc=new Corporate_Contract__c();
    cc.Name = 'Test Contract';
    cc.Admin_Fee__c = 10;
    cc.Contract_Start_Date__c = Date.newInstance(2010,01,01);
    cc.Contract_End_Date__c = Date.newInstance(2020,02,01);
    insert cc;
    }
   }

Comment: You need to trigger delete: `insert cc; delete cc; } }`